# Overwrite javascript file object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, file-upload

I am using javascript to upload file.
for which i have used,

```
$("#file").on("change", function(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var file = files[i];
    file.type = "abcd";  // MY AIM
   alert(file.type);     // NOT returning "abcd"
}
```

It is giving alert as image/jpg, but i want to overwrite my variable for a some browsers which are returning wrong file types.
Is there any way to do so?
please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change `type`, it's [a read-only property](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-type). You'll just have to send supplementary information to your server telling it the correct type separately.